# What is the source of this animated GIF of a couple slapping each other in play?

Tags: identification-request

Does anyone know the manga's name?

[image: Cute couple slapping each other in the face]

Thanks in advance n_n

Answer (score 7):

*Note: This is a bit too long for a comment, but I'm not really sure about my answer. If something is egregiously wrong, I'll delete this.*

I ran some reverse image searches and noticed that the GIF appeared to be created from [this image set](http://rinkizaki.tumblr.com/post/49946474834):

[image: non-GIF version of image]

The Tumblr source links to a now-deleted Pixiv entry by the user [ましき　＋　まこる](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=35560856). Given the lack of series-specific tags on both the first Tumblr source I found and [this one](http://kanzentai.tumblr.com/post/50309661333) -- they simply state "Pixiv" and some generic description tags -- I'm inclined to suspect that this might be original work (or at least some sort of doujinshi). However, I can't read the Japanese of the caption of the *second* source, and so I may be missing something from there. Moreover, since the original Pixiv image appears to have been removed, it's hard to say.

Comment: The caption on the second thing (らくがきとかまんがとか) means, I guess, "some sketches and manga". Nothing terribly enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

The characters may possibly (IF I am making sense of the reverse image search results) be Mirai Kuriyama and Hiroomi Nase from Beyond The Boundry, but the work is apparently original. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Boundary

Comment: What makes you think there is a resemblance?